# How to generate multivariate Gaussian distribution in R?

Tags: r, distribution

I want to simulate a multivariate Gaussian distribution for my model. 
Specifically, I want to randomly introduce a weak correlation between different dimensions. I know I should modify the covariance matrix, but I don't know how to do it randomly. Also, how can I force it to have unite variance in each dimension.

Here is my attempt:

```
# creat mean vector'
 mu<-rep(0,25)
# Creat covariance metrix:

Sigma<-diag(rep(1,25))

# Sample from multivariate distribution:

Data=mvrnorm(100,mu,Sigma)
```

Comment: `sample` to randomly select elements of the covariance matrix to change

Answer (score 0):

This should work for a single insertion. If you need to insert multiple correlations, you'll have to loop through this.

```
library(mvtnorm)
Sigma <- diag(1, 5) # create a (smaller) example cov matrix with unit variance on diagonal

# here we wish to sample 1 element in Sigma to insert a random
# covariance into. First we exclude the diagonal elements / indices
l <- 1:length(Sigma) 
n <- seq(1, length(Sigma), (1+ncol(Sigma)))  
set.seed(137)
s <- sample(l[! (l %in% n)], size= 1, replace= F)

# we must account for inserting the transpose indices as well.
ind_i <- s %% nrow(Sigma)
ind_j <- ceiling(s / nrow(Sigma))

# a random correlation (here between -1,1).
# obviously, if you want a "weak" correlation, you can modify the bounds
rand_cor <- runif(1, -1,1)  

Sigma[ind_i, ind_j] <- rand_cor # initial index
Sigma[ind_j, ind_i] <- rand_cor # the transpose index
```